# Highlight characters in string using different colors with PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, highlight

I'm trying to highlight separate characters (letters), in a string using 4 different colors. What I would like is...

Key:

,**Y**,2 = Red background/white text
  ,**Y**,1 = Red background/white text
  ,**T**, = Blue background/white text
  ,**N**\r\n = Green background/white text
  **word.it** = White background/grey text

The only way to correctly identify *only* the letters I want to highlight is by their position to other adjacent characters,e.g. commas, numbers and line returns, however I don't actually want to highlight the adjacent delimiters.

*See my HTML mockup of what I'm after here:

[image: Character Highlighting >>]

I've already tried using `preg_replace` but the code only allows me to highlight one character in the array in the color I want and not the others too. All letters get assigned just one color using this code.

```
$sentence = $resp;
$wordsToHighlight = array(",N\r\n", ",T,", "Y,1", "Y,2");
$modifiedData = preg_replace('/'.implode('|', $wordsToHighlight).'/', '<span style="background:#24aaff;"><b>$0</b></span><span style="background:#33cc33;"><b>$1</b></span><span style="background:#ff0000;"><b>$2</b></span><span style="background:ff0000;"><b>$3</b></span>', $sentence);
echo '<p class="names">' .$modifiedData. '</p>';
```

Comment: _“All letters get assigned just one color using this code.”_ - well you could start by providing an array of colors as well, or use what you need to replace as key and the color as value - and then you loop over that, and do the replacing for each tuple separately … no one said you _had to_ try and cram that all into one single preg_replace call to begin with, right?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your speedy reply. Excuse my naivity, but are you able to provide me with any sample code of what you mention? I am a bit puzzled.

Comment: `$wordsToHighlight = array(",N\r\n" => "red", ",T," => "blue", …)` - loop over that using foreach, so you get key and value, and then … use them to do one replacement operation at a time.

Comment: Hi, i've been trying to get this right for a few hours now with no joy. Can you tell me what code exactly I need to get it to highlight as per my screenshot above? I've had allsorts of variations but not the one I want. It's also echoing quadruple duplicate lines now.

Comment: Come to think of it, doing several replacements one after the other might not be the best idea, because then there’s an increased chance that you would replace already replaced stuff again. Using `preg_replace_callback` might make more sense here, but for that to work regarding the “look-up” of what color belongs to which match, you’d need an association between the actual match and the color - the requirement to only highlight part of the match makes that harder.